# date-fns isToday() returning a confusing value

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I am confused about the output of the date-fns `isToday()` function.

Running `new Date()` I currently get `2019-09-06T20:12:40.737Z`

I am running `2019-09-06T00:00:00.000Z` through `isToday()` and it is returning false.

I am also confused because when I stringify my date it return yesterday's date.

```
cost isToday = require('date-fns/isToday')

myDate === // 2019-09-06T00:00:00.000Z

console.log(new Date())
// 2019-09-06T20:12:40.737Z

console.log(isToday(myDate))
// false

console.log(myDate.toString())
// Thu Sep 05 2019 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

Is this a time zone thing? Am I misunderstanding the way that javascript dates are stored? Or is this a date-fns issue?

Comment: The documentation for that library is terrible so it's hard to say what it intends to do for that function. If your `myDate` variable is initialized to a UTC timestamp then it could definitely be a time zone thing.

Comment: Can you please share the code for isToday() function?

Comment: @FaraazMalak it's part of that library, it's not the OP's code

Comment: see [date-fns docs](https://date-fns.org/v2.1.0/docs/isToday)

Answer (score 2):

Something i figured

`new Date('2019-09-06T00:00:00.000Z')`
outputs to me Thu Sep 05 2019 21:00:00 GMT-0300

`new Date('2019-09-06T00:00:00.000')`
outputs to me Fri Sep 06 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300

Notice that the Z at the end makes Date treat it as timezone +00:00. I'd just drop it.